# No sound in OBS from capturing destop audio

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using Archlinux with up to date soft. I have set desktop capture with sound in OBS, but the red volume range doesn't change at all, though I have played music in the browser, nor sound is recorded at all. If I add mic capturing it works. If I start and stop recording the video file doesn't have audio as well Here's the screen:

[image]

and obs logs:

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
info: CPU Speed: 2725.460MHz
info: Physical Cores: 4, Logical Cores: 8
info: Physical Memory: 32046MB Total, 22761MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 5.1.15-arch1-1-ARCH
info: Distribution: "Arch Linux" Unknown
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.20.5
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_destroyed()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_program_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)
info: OBS 23.2.1-2 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
        samples per sec: 44100
        speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
info: Loading up OpenGL on adapter NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2
info: OpenGL loaded successfully, version 3.2.0 NVIDIA 430.26, shading language 1.50 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
info: ---------------------------------
info: video settings reset:
        base resolution:   1920x1080
        output resolution: 1280x720
        downscale filter:  Bicubic
        fps:               60/1
        format:            NV12
        YUV mode:          601/Partial
info: NV12 texture support not available
info: Audio monitoring device:
        name: Default
        id: default
info: ---------------------------------
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-ouput-ui.so'
libDeckLinkAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
info: No blackmagic support
info: NVENC supported
info: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
info: VLC found, VLC video source enabled
info: ---------------------------------
info:   Loaded Modules:
info:     vlc-video.so
info:     text-freetype2.so
info:     rtmp-services.so
info:     obs-x264.so
info:     obs-transitions.so
info:     obs-outputs.so
info:     obs-libfdk.so
info:     obs-filters.so
info:     obs-ffmpeg.so
info:     linux-v4l2.so
info:     linux-pulseaudio.so
info:     linux-jack.so
info:     linux-decklink.so
info:     linux-capture.so
info:     linux-alsa.so
info:     image-source.so
info:     frontend-tools.so
info:     decklink-ouput-ui.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: ==== Startup complete ===============================================
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 12.2'
info: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 48000 Hz, 6 channels
info: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_output.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_SB_Omni_Surround_5.1_000000Hk-00.analog-surround-51.monitor'
info: pulse-am: Prevented feedback-loop in 'default'
info: Switched to scene 'Scene 2'
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: Loaded scenes:
info: - scene 'Scene 2':
info:     - source: 'Desktop Audio' (pulse_output_capture)
info:         - monitoring: monitor and output
info: ------------------------------------------------
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
info: adding 23 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 23 milliseconds (source: Desktop Audio)

info: adding 23 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 46 milliseconds (source: Desktop Audio)

qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 4692, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 4715, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 4725, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 4747, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 5023, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 5037, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 5040, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
info: ---------------------------------
info: [NVENC encoder: 'simple_h264_recording'] settings:
        rate_control: CQP
        bitrate:      0
        cqp:          21
        keyint:       250
        preset:       hq
        profile:      high
        width:        1280
        height:       720
        2-pass:       false
        b-frames:     2
        GPU:          0

[h264_nvenc @ 0x5592daaf5640] Using global_quality with nvenc is deprecated. Use qp instead.
info: libfdk_aac encoder created
info: libfdk_aac bitrate: 128, channels: 2
info: ==== Recording Start ===============================================
info: [ffmpeg muxer: 'simple_file_output'] Writing file '/home/andrew/Pictures/2019-07-07 11-37-05.flv'...
[flv @ 0x55605eb64680] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[flv @ 0x55605eb64680] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 8830, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 8844, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 8847, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 8859, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9154, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9176, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9186, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9202, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9222, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9238, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9253, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9263, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9284, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9295, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9329, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9345, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9356, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9377, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 9388, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
info: [ffmpeg muxer: 'simple_file_output'] Output of file '/home/andrew/Pictures/2019-07-07 11-37-05.flv' stopped
info: Output 'simple_file_output': stopping
info: Output 'simple_file_output': Total frames output: 205
info: Output 'simple_file_output': Total drawn frames: 219
info: ==== Recording Stop ================================================
info: libfdk_aac encoder destroyed
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 10954, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 10972, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 10975, resource id: 146800806, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
info: ==== Shutting down ==================================================
info: Switched to scene '(null)'
info: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_output.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_SB_Omni_Surround_5.1_000000Hk-00.analog-surround-51.monitor'
info: pulse-input: Got 5473 packets with 954139 frames
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 13246
error: Failed to make context current.
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 13248
error: Failed to make context current.
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 13250
error: Failed to make context current.
error: Failed to fetch parent window geometry!
error: X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter), Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error), Serial: 13252
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation), Serial: 13253
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 13255
error: Failed to make context current.
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 13257
error: Failed to make context current.
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: [Scripting] Total detached callbacks: 0
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 521.116 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 2.79 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 0.794 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 406.532 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 1.109 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 319.535 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.085 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.101 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 142.398 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitOBSCallbacks: 0.002 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitHotkeys: 0.028 ms
info:      ┣obs_load_all_modules: 90.765 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-ouput-ui.so): 0.668 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(frontend-tools.so): 57.176 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(image-source.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-alsa.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-capture.so): 0.221 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-decklink.so): 0.103 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-jack.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pulseaudio.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-v4l2.so): 0 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-ffmpeg.so): 0.678 ms
info:      ┃ ┃ ┗nvenc_check: 0.613 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-filters.so): 0.008 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-libfdk.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-outputs.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-transitions.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-x264.so): 0 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(rtmp-services.so): 0.108 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(text-freetype2.so): 0.005 ms
info:      ┃ ┗obs_init_module(vlc-video.so): 1.911 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetOutputs: 0.08 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::CreateHotkeys: 0.022 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitService: 0.927 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitPrimitives: 0.181 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::Load: 8.247 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0.057 ms, median=0.214 ms, max=65.179 ms, 99th percentile=4.116 ms, 99.7484% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0 ms, median=0.185 ms, max=1.611 ms, 99th percentile=0.662 ms
info:  ┗receive_audio: min=0.007 ms, median=0.274 ms, max=1.542 ms, 99th percentile=0.46 ms, 0.185484 calls per parent call
info:    ┣buffer_audio: min=0 ms, median=0.001 ms, max=0.013 ms, 99th percentile=0.007 ms
info:    ┗do_encode: min=0.079 ms, median=0.269 ms, max=1.54 ms, 99th percentile=0.451 ms
info:      ┗encode(simple_aac_recording): min=0.076 ms, median=0.26 ms, max=0.442 ms, 99th percentile=0.419 ms
info: obs_graphics_thread(16.6667 ms): min=0.159 ms, median=1.387 ms, max=46.546 ms, 99th percentile=6.108 ms, 99.5008% below 16.667 ms
info:  ┣tick_sources: min=0.001 ms, median=0.013 ms, max=0.165 ms, 99th percentile=0.024 ms
info:  ┣output_frame: min=0.115 ms, median=0.554 ms, max=46.428 ms, 99th percentile=3.382 ms
info:  ┃ ┣gs_context(video->graphics): min=0.115 ms, median=0.548 ms, max=46.427 ms, 99th percentile=2.913 ms
info:  ┃ ┃ ┣render_video: min=0.01 ms, median=0.175 ms, max=2.029 ms, 99th percentile=0.749 ms
info:  ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣render_main_texture: min=0.006 ms, median=0.137 ms, max=0.727 ms, 99th percentile=0.217 ms
info:  ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣render_output_texture: min=0.001 ms, median=0.166 ms, max=1.514 ms, 99th percentile=0.305 ms, 0.182196 calls per parent call
info:  ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣render_convert_texture: min=0.001 ms, median=0.113 ms, max=0.706 ms, 99th percentile=0.357 ms, 0.182196 calls per parent call
info:  ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗stage_output_texture: min=0 ms, median=0.083 ms, max=1.045 ms, 99th percentile=0.827 ms, 0.182196 calls per parent call
info:  ┃ ┃ ┣gs_flush: min=0.001 ms, median=0.027 ms, max=2.978 ms, 99th percentile=0.077 ms
info:  ┃ ┃ ┗download_frame: min=0 ms, median=0.005 ms, max=0.01 ms, 99th percentile=0.01 ms, 0.182196 calls per parent call
info:  ┃ ┗output_video_data: min=0.14 ms, median=0.374 ms, max=2.579 ms, 99th percentile=2.108 ms, 0.178869 calls per parent call
info:  ┗render_displays: min=0.042 ms, median=0.796 ms, max=18.382 ms, 99th percentile=2.181 ms
info: video_thread(video): min=0.481 ms, median=1.197 ms, max=3.82 ms, 99th percentile=2.036 ms
info:  ┗receive_video: min=0.48 ms, median=1.194 ms, max=3.817 ms, 99th percentile=2.033 ms
info:    ┗do_encode: min=0.479 ms, median=1.193 ms, max=3.816 ms, 99th percentile=2.031 ms
info:      ┗encode(simple_h264_recording): min=0.476 ms, median=1.181 ms, max=3.81 ms, 99th percentile=1.802 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25.087 ms, median=25.296 ms, max=90.241 ms, 92.1914% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 7.80856% higher)
info: obs_graphics_thread(16.6667 ms): min=3.436 ms, median=16.667 ms, max=46.557 ms, 98.6678% within ±2% of 16.667 ms (0.666112% lower, 0.666112% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 0
```

I have installed this version of sotware:

```
local/obs-studio 23.2.1-2
local/linux 5.1.15.arch1-
local/alsa-lib 1.1.9-1
local/alsa-plugins 1.1.9-2
local/alsa-tools 1.1.7-1
local/alsa-utils 1.1.9-1
local/lib32-alsa-lib 1.1.9-1
local/lib32-alsa-plugins 1.1.9-1
local/pulseaudio-alsa 2-4
local/zita-alsa-pcmi 0.3.2-1
local/lib32-libpulse 12.2-1
local/libcanberra-pulse 0.30+2+gc0620e4-2
local/pulseaudio 12.2-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to go to the "Recording" tab of `pavucontrol` and to unmute the OBS stream. I don't known why it was muted.